# Github API - refs/tags

Tags: java, git, api, github

I am working on GitHub enterprise (but it should be the same as github.com) and try to get simple query using the API. I am checking if tag exists.

The GET call is:

```
https://<HOST>/api/v3/repos/<ORG>/<REPO>/git/refs/tags/2.0-0-SNAPSHOT-b1364-ci
```

The tag exists so it returns answer with JSON:

```
"ref": "refs/tags/2.0-0-SNAPSHOT-b1364-ci"
```

But:

`https://<HOST>/api/v3/repos/<ORG>/<REPO>/git/refs/tags/2.0-0-SNAPSHOT-b1364`

Same call without last 3 chars (**ci**) returns the same answer. 
Means that The API returns based on `contains` and not `equals`.

I don't know why GitHub did it in that way. My simple question is:

- What is the best way to know if `TAG` exists on repository (in Java)?

Comment: Check if what you get in the response is identical to what you sent?